# Ionic angularjs Android App

Tags: android, angularjs

I am developing an android app using the Ionic framework. I am trying to build the basic fileupload system.

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <input type="file" name="image">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

After selecting the image, it doesnot show original filename. It shows some random filename without extension.

Here is the screenshots. I have selected the images-2.jpeg

[image]

[image]

Thanks to all

Comment: If you can put some code in this question, that would be helpful RAJ.

Comment: I just added a form and checking thats it.

Comment: can you check a simple input field file in the android browser? its not returning the original file name.  If i check this is in the chrome it returns the correct filename images-2.jpeg. You can understand my question?

Comment: can you try enctype="text/plain", and see whats the result ? EDIT: Sorry that wont help !

Comment: any idea? first of all you understood my issue?